# Regarding Azure AD Connect directory configuration

Tags: azure, azure-devops, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Whether Only the Active Directory forests should be added in the connect your directories window of Azure AD Connect or we can also add domains in the connect your directories window of Azure AD Connect ?

Attached the connect your directories window of AAD Connect
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can able to add domain in azure ad connect please check this below workaround

- Run this following command on that system try to install azure ad module and login

```php
     $msolcred = get-credential
    connect-msolservice -credential $msolcred
    New-MsolFederatedDomain –SupportMultipleDomain –DomainName
```

Try to ***launch*** Azure AD Connect from the ***desktop -> manage federation ->Federation ad domain ->click azure AD domain***

[image]

[image]

[image]